# Irreducible projective characters of degree one for a group $G$.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

It is known for a group $G$ with Schur multiplier $M(G)$ that the set of ordinary characters Irr$(G)$ is associated with the trivial factor set 1 in the cohomology class $[1]$ of $M(G)$. Since the order of a cohomology class $[\alpha]\in M(G)$ must divide the degrees of the characters in the set IrrProj$(G,\alpha)$ of irreducible projective characters of $G$ with nontrivial factor set $\alpha$, it follows that IrrProj$(G,\alpha)$ cannot contains any character of degree one. Is it at all possible for $G$ to have a projective character of degree one besides the ones that are contained in the set Irr$(G)$?

Comment: I don't think so. In a covering group $F$ of $G$ with $F/M(G) \cong G$, we have $M(G) \le [F,F]$, so $M(G)$ is in the kernel of any representation of $F$ of degree $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll make my comment into an answer. You didn't say that you were assuming that $G$ is a finite group, but I think you probably are, since your remark about dividing degrees would not make sense otherwise.

Let $F$ be a covering group of  $G$, so $F$ is maximal with the property that it has a normal subgroup $M$ with $M \le [F,F] \cap Z(F)$ and $F/M \cong G$.

It is a standard result that every projective representation of (a finite group) $G$ is induced by an ordinary representation of $F$. But a representation on $F$ of degree one has abelian image, and so it has $[F,F]$ and hence $M$ in its kernel. So it corresponds to an ordinary representation of $G$.